# How to load an extention in php's built-in server?

Tags: php

In the PHPs built-in server, I can see there are two `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` files, now, since I am trying to enable curl I un-commented both files and restarted the server, but everytime I need to use curl, php says, curl extention is not loaded, even with I checked even with `extension_loaded()` method, it seems like PHP is not reading from the ini files, or both files are not the real ini config file, and whenever I do something like `dl('php_curl.dll')` it says, undefined function `dl()` because, I guess dl is deprecated, so I am looking to find out the problem, if the ini files are not the one's I am checking or how to load this extention and where

Answer (score 1):

Use php.ini, not php.ini-something_else. You can check which php.ini is being used by creating a page with this line:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

and viewing it in your web browser.

Comment: I can't seem to find where the php.ini is located, because there isn't one

Answer (score 1):

Those 2 files are just examples and never loaded. You are supposed to copy *either* of those files to `php.ini`.

Comment: I can't seem to find where the `php.ini` is located, because there isn't one;

Comment: @piosoiq That's exactly the point. Those 2 files are "suggested settings", but one has defaults for development servers and one has defaults for production servers. This information is clearly stated at the end of the PHP install process. **Basically:** Make a copy of `php.ini-development` (or `php.ini-production`) *in the same folder* and rename it `php.ini`.